# Can a class reassign itself to another variable within itself?

Tags: java, class, object, this

For an assignment, I'm having to resize an array within a class, and due to the classes nature, it is easier to just create a new object of the class and then reassign itself?

Let me try and explain with code

```
public class foo {

     // String Array instance
     private String[] array;

     // Constructor with a String array as a variable to initialize it's instance
     public foo(String[] array){
          this.array = array;
     }

     public void reassign() {
          String[] differentArray = {};
          foo temp = new foo(differentArray);

          // Now here is where my problem lies

          this = temp; 

          // out of this I get the following error
          // The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable
     }
}
// Let also just say that for the sake of argument, I can't reassign
// 'array' to 'differentArray'
```

So, how would we make this work? Do I just have to hard code around it or is there a better way to change the reference to the object itself?

Any Advice would be appriciated

Comment: You can't change the `array` reference without assigning it the new reference. You can only obfuscate the reassignment.

Comment: It seems the answers that I'm getting just have me doing some hard coding which turns out to be what I did anyway. 

The main question I had though, was could I reassign 'foo' (the class itself that I was in) to a different 'foo' (an object made inside the class). I think the answer is no, due to the methods not being static (I think). 

Thanks for all your input though, it was really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Proceed this way:

**Foo.java**

```
public class Foo{

    // String Array instance
    public String[] array; // I made this variable 'public' so that it would be accessible to the main method's class

    // Constructor with a String array as a variable to initialize it's instance
    public Foo(String[] array){
        this.array = array;
    }

    public void reassign(int length) {
        array = new String[length];
        array[0] = "Hello"; // String to display in the main() method
    }
}
```

**App.java**

```
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        String[] tab = new String[1];
        tab[0] = "TempValue";
        Foo myArray = new Foo(tab);
        myArray.reassign(2); // new array with size = 2
        System.out.println(myArray.array[0]);
        myArray.array[1] = "World";
        System.out.println(myArray.array[1]);
    }
}
```

This prints :

```
Hello
World
```

to the console. Which proves that the `reassign` method worked.

Answer (score 0):

You can either mutate the class by reassigning the internal array: instead of `String[] differentArray = {};` do `array = {};`. That will lose the previously stored information.

Or you can return a new foo object:

```
public Foo reassign() {
  Foo temp = new Foo(...);
  return temp;
}
```

Which is appropriate depends on what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: The second option sounds more toward what I was going for, it's just I want the class itself to become the new 'Foo' object I created inside of it.

Comment: Would you mind explaining? I'm confused why it's not so.